# using $_session to store variables with dynamic data retrieved from an api with json format to use in defferent pages

Tags: php, api, session-variables

hey guys i'm new here and currently working on my first project which is an ERP kindof
i'm using google spreadsheets api to retrieve data from a spreadsheet and echo it in a html table but i need to re-use some of that data in multiple pages with multiple tables
i retrieve data from a json file as rows and i echo them in a table respectively for a loop
the problem is to use that data in other php files i store the variables in a session but when i echo the session in the other file it prints just the first row over all that column is there ana other way or a fix to do this please help !!!
note that in the other page i also retrieve some data from different sheets

here is the code i'm using and the first page to retrieve data and print it in the table

```
<?php
define("API_KEY", "XXXXXXXXXXXX");

$url = sprintf('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1R8cETVG5XT08iCgZjWOJXSw-HmC_MDOXkjZntEVys40/values/RECAP!AF4:AI?key=AIzaSyD6Mrl9C700rrEKutzvmZa2_43KLEd1sQE', API_KEY);
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
$rows = $json->values;
?>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Nom</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Prénom</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Zone</th>
                    <th class="text-center">RIB</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach($rows as $row){
                    echo '<tr>';
                    $_SESSION['nom_employe'] = $row[3];
                    $_SESSION['prenom_employe'] = $prenom_employe;
                    $prenom_employe = $row[3];
                    $zone_employe = $row[2];
                    $_SESSION['calc'] = (($row[3])+($row[3]));
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $_SESSION['nom_employe'] . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $prenom_employe . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $zone . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $_SESSION['calc'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the code i'm using in the page i'm having trouble with

```
<!-- container start -->
<?php
define("API_KEY", "XXXXXXXXXXXX");

$url = sprintf('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/13I_NndK33-AgnfqELjDn--6pIBLz10dOmH83_KoLqNg/values/SuiviCA!B5:P?key=AIzaSyD6Mrl9C700rrEKutzvmZa2_43KLEd1sQE', API_KEY);
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
$rows = $json->values;
?>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">DATE FACRURE</th>
                    <th class="text-center">NOM DE CLIENT</th>
                    <th class="text-center">N° FACTURE</th>
                    <th class="text-center">N° BL</th>
                    <th class="text-center">SEMAINE N°</th>
                    <th class="text-center">MOIS</th>
                    <th class="text-center">SEMAINE</th>
                    <th class="text-center">MT EN EURO</th>
                    <th class="text-center">MT $</th>
                    <th class="text-center">MT MAD</th>
                    <th class="text-center">N° DUM</th>
                    <th class="text-center">AVIS D'EXPORT</th>
                    <th class="text-center">DATE DE PAIE</th>
                    <th class="text-center">MODE DE PAIMENT</th>
                    <th class="text-center">REMARQUE</th>


                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php

                    foreach($rows as $row){
                    echo '<tr>';
                    $date_facture_suivi_ca = $row[0];
                    $nom_client_suivi_ca = $row[1];
                    $_SESSION['facture'] = $row[2];
                    $num_bl_suivi_ca = $_SESSION['prenom_employe'];
                    $sem_num_suivi_ca = $row[4];
                    $mois_suivi_ca = $row[5];
                    $sem_suivi_ca = $row[6];
                    $mt_euro_suivi_ca = $row[7];
                    $mt_dollar_suivi_ca = $row[8];
                    $mt_mad_suivi_ca = $row[9];
                    $num_dum_suivi_ca = $row[10];
                    $avis_export_suivi_ca = $row[11];
                    $date_paie_suivi_ca = $row[12];
                    $mode_paiment_suivi_ca = $row[13];
                    $remarque_suivi_ca = $row[14];

                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $date_facture_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $nom_client_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $_SESSION['prenom_employe'] . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $num_bl_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $sem_num_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $mois_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $sem_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $mt_euro_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $mt_dollar_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $mt_mad_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $num_dum_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $avis_export_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $date_paie_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $mode_paiment_suivi_ca . '</td>';
                    echo "<td class='text-center'>" . $remarque_suivi_ca . '</td>';

                    echo '</tr>';
                }?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- container end -->
```

Comment: you are always overriding the current session value in your `foreach` loop. save the `$rows` in the session and loop in your second page again

Comment: how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

You always overriding
`prenom_employe` with the last row value `$_SESSION['prenom_employe'] = $prenom_employe`;
You can create some registry and store all `$prenom_employe` values to it, after that you will be able to display those values in another place from that "registry" and values will be different

Comment: it gives me undefined array but it shows the results the problem is that the first value is duplicated over the other rows

Comment: You sholdn`t override value in session in foreach, it will have always the last value. Think about and try to hold data in separate keys for each row, maybe try serialize array with data and in other piece of code unserialize it and use what you need.

Answer (score -1):

To start using session cookies you must ad "session_start();" at the very top of your page above the headers

session_start();

Comment: If that were the only issue, it wouldn't print the first row either.

Comment: i did indeed used it at the top if i didn't it wouldn't have showd the results the problem is instead of showing the value of each row it shows the first row value on all of them unlike the first page so i guess the mistake im doing is in the second page where am getting the data or maybe while priting i actually dont know !!